# Authentication parameters missing (401) in python request

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

I want to get the data points from the graph below (https://index.mysteel.com/price/getChartMultiCity_1_0.html)

[image: Graph]

I found out from Developer Tools -> Network -> XHR that a request is made when I explore the graph. The response has all the data needed, like date and price.

If I just copy the request URL and fetch the data with python's `requests`, I get the correct response. Example:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://index.mysteel.com/zs/newprice/getBaiduChartMultiCity.ms?catalog=%25E8%259E%25BA%25E7%25BA%25B9%25E9%2592%25A2_%3A_%25E8%259E%25BA%25E7%25BA%25B9%25E9%2592%25A2&city=%25E4%25B8%258A%25E6%25B5%25B7%3A15278&spec=HRB400E%252020MM_%3A_HRB400E_20MM&startTime=2021-08-10&endTime=2021-08-12&callback=json')
r.json()
{'marketDatas': .........}
```

However, if I change the values of `endTime` or `startTime` query parameters, I get a `401` error:

> Missing authentication parameters!

It looks like I can only send requests that are already sent from my browser (I'm running a jupyter notebook in the same browser). Even if I add request headers like in the Network tab, I still get the same error:

```
params= {'catalog':'%E8%9E%BA%E7%BA%B9%E9%92%A2_:_%E8%9E%BA%E7%BA%B9%E9%92%A2' ,'city':'%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7:15278' ,
         'spec':'HRB400E%2020MM_:_HRB400E_20MM' ,'startTime':'2021-08-10', 'endTime':'2021-08-12', 'callback':'json'}

headers = {'Host': 'index.mysteel.com',
         'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
          'Referer': 'https://index.mysteel.com/price/getChartMultiCity_1_0.html',
          'appKey': '47EE3F12CF0C443F851EFDA73AC815',
         'Cookie':'href=https%3A%2F%2Findex.mysteel.com%2Fprice%2FgetChartMultiCity_1_0.html; accessId=5d36a9e0-919c-11e9-903c-ab24d11b; pageViewNum=2'}

url = 'https://index.mysteel.com/zs/newprice/getBaiduChartMultiCity.ms'
r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
```

What am I missing here? I am not authenticating myself in the browser, so there shouldn't be any authentication issues. Is there some other parameter missing in my headers dict?

PS: These are all the request headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,sq;q=0.8,de;q=0.7
appKey: 47EE3F12CF0C443F851EFDA73AC815
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: href=https%3A%2F%2Findex.mysteel.com%2Fprice%2FgetChartMultiCity_1_0.html; accessId=5d36a9e0-919c-11e9-903c-ab24d11b; pageViewNum=2
dnt: 1
Host: index.mysteel.com
Referer: https://index.mysteel.com/price/getChartMultiCity_1_0.html
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="92", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="92"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
sec-gpc: 1
sign: D404184969BF3B8C081A9F0C913AF68E
timestamp: 1629136315665
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36
version: 1.0.0
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: "*I am not authenticating myself in the browser, so there shouldn't be any authentication issues*" Authentication isn't the only thing that can change what you'd need to send to the server between requests. One-time nonces, time-based authorizations, etc. are also factors to consider (among others).

Comment: @esqew thanks for the comment. Could you point out which of the factors you mentioned  exists in my case? Is it possible to find that out from the request headers alone? I did notice `timestamp` and `sign` headers, but I don't know whether any (or both) of them is the cause here.

Comment: “*I don't know whether any (or both) of them is the cause here.*” And, like most undocumented APIs, this is probably by design to dissuade you from even attempting this type of unauthorized data collection in the first place. The best place to start, in my opinion, is to try and see how each of the values correlates to one another, as well as how it correlates to the current time, and go from there. Alternatively, it may also be possible to inspect the broader JavaScript of the site you’re attempting to scrape from and reverse the algorithm they use to generate the request in the first place.

Comment: @esqew I see. Thank you for the tip, that was quite insightful.